# How can I check if a list exist in a dictionary of lists in the same order

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary of lists,

```
C = {}
li = []
li.append(x)
C[ind] = li
```

And I want to check if another list is a member of this dictionary.

```
for s in C.values():
    s.append(w)
```

Python checks it for any occurrences of the values in s and the dictionary values. But I want to check if any of the lists in the dictionary is identical to the given list.

How can I do it?

Comment: do you mean identical lists or a subset?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: I mean identical lists. Sorry I'm editing the question.

Comment: @ndpu sorting doesn't help I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `any` for a list of lists:

```
d = {1 : [1,2,3], 2: [2,1]}
lsts = [[1,2],[2,1]]
print(any(x in d.values() for x in lsts))
True

d = {1:[1,2,3],2:[1,2]}
lsts = [[3,2,1],[2,1]]
print(any(x in d.values() for x in lsts))
False
```

Or `in` for a single list:

```
lst = [1,2]
lst in d.itervalues()
```

Python will compare each element of both lists so they will have to have the same order to be equal, even if they have the  same elements inside the order must also be the same so a simple comparison will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`in` does the trick perfectly, because it does a comparison with each element behind the scenes, so it works even for mutable elements:

```
lst in d.values()
```